# Left Joining Three tables with Subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join, multiple-tables

[Check this fiddle for DB and tables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f137a/57)

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN offertran ot 
ON p.prod_id = ot.prod_id
LEFT JOIN Offers o
ON ot.offer_id =  (SELECT id FROM Offers 
                   Where dF<=3 AND dt>=3)

ORDER BY o.id DESC, 
          p.prod_id ASC
LIMIT 20
```

The Output is:

```
| PROD_ID | CATEGORY_ID | PROD_NAME |  BRAND | PRICE | STATUS |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|      p3 |          c1 |     prod3 | brand3 |  3000 | active |
|      p3 |          c1 |     prod3 | brand3 |  3000 | active |
|      p1 |          c1 |     prod1 | brand1 |  1000 | active |
|      p2 |          c2 |     prod2 | brand2 |  2000 | active |
|      p4 |          c2 |     prod4 | brand1 |  4000 | active |
|      p5 |          c1 |     prod5 | brand2 |  5000 | active |
|      p6 |          c2 |     prod6 | brand3 |  6000 | active |
```

But, here as you can see `p3` is shown two times. I dont know why..
I had tried all the possible ways but I cant find any remedies.. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in

```
LEFT JOIN Offers o
ON ot.offer_id =  (SELECT id FROM Offers 
                   Where dF<=3 AND dt>=3)
```

You join ot.offer_id with constant values (there is no meaning you select them from offers table).

The correct way:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN offertran ot 
ON p.prod_id = ot.prod_id
LEFT JOIN Offers o
ON ot.offer_id = o.id AND o.dF<=3 AND o.dt>=3
ORDER BY o.id DESC, 
          p.prod_id ASC
LIMIT 20
```

Look at [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f137a/107)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the join condition between 'o' and 'ot' is missing:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN offertran ot 
ON p.prod_id = ot.prod_id
LEFT JOIN Offers o
ON ot.offer_id IN(SELECT id FROM Offers 
               Where dF<=3 AND dt>=3)
**AND ot.offer_id = o.id***
ORDER BY o.id DESC, 
      p.prod_id ASC
LIMIT 20
```

Or maybe I missed something and didn't undertand what you want to get from the DB with your query.

Answer (score 1):

May be you're looking for this. This will return p3 only once. 
You missed the o.id in Second Left Join condition.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN offertran ot 
ON p.prod_id = ot.prod_id
LEFT JOIN Offers o
ON o.id =  (SELECT id FROM Offers 
            Where dF<=3 AND dt>=3)

ORDER BY o.id DESC, 
          p.prod_id ASC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: this is not what i wanted.. here I lost all my sequences.. anyways.. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two records in `offertran` or `Products` with the PROD_ID of p3.  You could change it to be `SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM ...` and that way any duplicate rows will be ignored.

Just to see what `offertran` is returning, change you `select p.*` to `select *`

Comment: I have only one record of p3 Adam. Thanks for your reply